# Z3 invalid function application: not to false

Tags: z3, smt

I have the following line in my program:

```
return Z3_mk_not(ctx, term);
```

When I run the program, Z3 fails at this line with the following error message:

```
WARNING: invalid function application, sort mismatch on argument at position 1
WARNING: (define not Bool Bool) applied to: false of sort Bool

Error: type error
```

... does anybody know what to make of this? I'm using Z3 version 4.3.1 with the new solvers API.

`valgrind` does not report any memory violations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `term` in question was in the wrong `Z3_context`. The error message was just slightly misleading, and along with the fact that `valgrind` didn't complain this wasn't the thing I considered first.